# Can't deploy basic android app with Android Studio on Windows Vista with JDK 8

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, android-emulator, windows-vista

I have a Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit computer. I am running the stable Android Studio 3.2.1 with the JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly set to the stable C:\Program Files\Jaba\jdk1.8.0_191. I had to updated this JDK location in android studio to get this to work. I can't run the latest Java 11 SDK because it only runs on 64-bit computers. So, I have an Android 7.0 Nougat smartphone with developer options enabled. I have tried to compile the My First App from developer.android.com/training/basics/fireball/running-app . But cannot get it deployed neither onto any emulator nor onto my device. I try Run...  from Android Studio but even though my device is detected I cannot deploy my app to my smartphone. The driver is installed successfully. Any idea what the problem might be, and whether I can fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the 32 bit Android Studio versiln and just install it. It will install a compatible JVM for 32 bit.

Comment: Was this the problem though?

Comment: Will I be able to deeply apps to newer phones worth it?

Comment: Yes of course, the App will run normally on new Phones

Comment: What is the latest 32 bit version and where do I find it?

Comment: In the same page of 64bit dowbload: https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

Comment: I've tried installing the 32 bit version but encounter this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53857565/10537436