# Android Studio: Error: module not specified but can't select a module to choose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, runtime, windows-vista

I'm running Android Studio 3.2.1, 32-bit on Windows Vista with JRE 1.8.0 x86 and JetBrains s.r.o OpenJDK.

My default app seems to build fine although Gradle takes some time, but when I run it, it prompts me with an "Edit Configurations..." dialog and then says "Click the + button to create a new configuration based on default settings." from which I select "Android App" on the left, but then where the "Module:" field is I can only select "" so I cannot run my app.

The error I get at the bottom is: `Error: Module not specified`.

What should I do so that I can run my app on a phone or emulator?